# Magicento Notification: Error requesting trial license, please try again later

Tags: magento, phpstorm

I am getting this error when using trial version installed directly from PhpStorm. First of all popup asks for email for sending key of trial version, then the notification appears.

Magicento : 2.4.0
Operating system : Mac os
PhpStorm : 2017.2.4

Comment: Could be firewall or some proxy issue. Better check `idea.log` file for possible details (Help | Show Log in XX). Then also check https://github.com/enriquepiatti/Magicento/issues